# Multikey indexing in rails mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, multikey

I want to store data in this format.

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId(...)
 "title": "Grocery Quality"
 "comments": [
    { author_id: ObjectId(...)
      date: Date(...)
      text: "Please expand the cheddar selection." },
    { author_id: ObjectId(...)
      date: Date(...)
      text: "Please expand the mustard selection." },
    { author_id: ObjectId(...)
      date: Date(...)
      text: "Please expand the olive selection." }
 ]
}
```

I'm confused as to how to achieve this format for my data.

I am using mongoid; does Mongoid support Multikey Indexing?

How can use mongoid to achieve my desired format and behaviour?

Comment: I'm facing same problem.

Comment: What do you want to create index on?

Comment: @gami What is the question actual looking for I'm confuse how to create embed document or how to create multi-indexing Mongoid doesnot support multikey indexing it something MONGODB would do

Comment: @Viran then how to configure such db collection with mongoid?

Comment: @Ganeshkunwar I thought the question was from Gami what is field u want to index on since the OP itself has not specified that detail and it viren

Comment: @Viran, I have faced same problem and not getting solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got your doubt correctly but as I can't comment I'm answering right away. If it isnt this what you asked, please explain a little bit more =)

You have your model with those fields you wrote before, I will call it Post model. For the comments on it, I would suggest you create another model callend Comment and embed it on the Post model:

```
class Post
  field: title
  embeds_many :comments
end

class Comment
  field :date
  field :text
  has_one :author
  embedded_in :post
end
```

And to index the comments on the Post model you could do:

```
index({ :"comments.updated_at" => 1 })
```